# Recent behavior changes in ColdFusion's RegEx engine?

Tags: java, coldfusion, windows-server-2016

We run ColdFusion 2018 on a Windows 2016 server with IIS.

We rebooted the Windows server on Jan 16, 2020 as part of routine maintenance. The next day we started seeing isolated stack overflow errors when users posted long strings (~2500 chars) in form data. The reboot seems unrelated but is the only recent change in our environment. Users have successfully submitted data equal to or greater in length for a number of years.

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError 
at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source) 
[Repeats many more times....]
```

The error originated from the "REFindNoCase" line of the code below, which checks for malicious-looking input coming from submitted forms.

```
var failedTest = false;
var doZealousTesting = true;
var badTagsAndEvents = "SCRIPT|OBJECT|APPLET|EMBED|FORM|LAYER|ILAYER|FRAME|IFRAME|FRAMESET|HREF|SRC|PARAM|META|onClick|onDblClick|onKeyDown|onKeyPress|onKeyUp|onMouseDown|onMouseOut|onMouseUp|onMouseOver|onBlur|onChange|onFocus|onSelect|javascript";
var zealousRegex = "((\%3C)|<)(.)+((\%3E)|>)";
var conservativeRegex = "((\%3C)|<)(.)*(#badTagsAndEvents#)+(.)*((\%3E)|>)";
var regexTest = iif(doZealousTesting,de(zealousRegex),de(conservativeRegex));
for (key in form) {
  failedTest = (failedTest or REFindNoCase(regexTest,left(form[key],3999)) neq 0);
}
```

Are we missing some inherent problem with the code?

(By the way, we were able to quell the errors by setting ColdFusion's "useJavaAsRegexEngine" flag to true.)

Comment: Re "*Is it possible the recent Windows patch could have changed the Perl regex engine?*", No. But I strongly doubt that Perl is involved here.

Comment: I'll edit the question title to de-emphasize the Windows part. According to our systems team no patch was applied. Just a reboot of the server plus a run of the MS Malicious Software Removal tool.

Comment: Similar bug filed and closed in 2016, https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4165797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2016 Adobe link given by @DWR ([reReplaceNoCase is throwing a java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4165797)) offers two explanations for how regex could cause a stack overflow unexpectedly.

1. change in jvm version (probably in conjunction w/ #2)
2. -Xss property reset at too small a value

Windows, CF, and the RegEx engine don't have anything to do with the issue. Stack size is the main variable at play. The solutions given by Adobe were to "increase the value of the Xss property in jvm.config or improve your regex pattern." Our solution was to set the "useJavaAsRegexEngine" property to true. For whatever reason, the Java engine parses the regex we were using more efficiently.